# Error in executing ifelse statements on multiple columns of various csv files in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have various .csv files. Each file has multiple columns but not all files have all the columns. I need to do some quality check on all the columns present in a file, and on all the files. Quality checks are as follows:

```
1) if ABC < 35 and ABC > 1.5*XYZ*MNO^1.1, consider it as NULL
2) if DEF < 20 and DEF > 1.5*XYZ*MNO^1.5*PQR, consider it as NULL   (ABC, DEF, MNO, PQR, XYZ are column names)
```

Using the code given below, I tried to execute above equations on all the columns of all the csv files but it is giving me an error. Also, I am not sure if the ifelse part of the code should be modified because as I said that not all columns are present in all the files, so I want a logic that states if column ABC is present in a files, then apply the given upper and lower limits on ABC column and likewise for all the columns. Could anyone please help me in correcting the code.

```
setwd("F:/Test")
set.seed(1234)

files_list <- list.files(path = "F:/Test", pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
dt_list <- lapply(files_list, readr::read_csv)

res_list <- list()
for (i in 1:length(dt_list)) {
  res_list[[i]] <- assign(
    x = paste0("res_df", i),
    value = data.frame(
      matrix(
        ncol = ncol(dt_list[[i]]),
        nrow = nrow(dt_list[[i]])
      )
    )
  )
}

# first, loop over the list of data frames
for (i in 1:length(dt_list)) {

  # next, loop over the columns of the ith data frame, performing the test on each
  for (j in 1:ncol(dt_list[[i]])) {

        # set an ifelse statement to categorize the values of each columns according to the test 
    result <- ifelse(
      test = dt_list[[i]][["ABC (m**2)"]] < 35 | dt_list[[i]][["ABC (m**2)"]] > 1.5*XYZ*MNO^1.1, # the test condition (m**2) is the units of ABC column
      yes = "Valid", # The value of the result if the above test is "TRUE"
      no = "Invalid" # The value if the test is "FALSE"
    )

    result <- ifelse(
      test = dt_list[[i]][["DEF (K)"] < 20 | dt_list[[i]][["DEF (K)"]] > 1.5*XYZ*MNO^1.5*PQR, # the test condition (K) is the units of DEF column
      yes = "Valid", # The value of the result if the above test is "TRUE"
      no = "Invalid" # The value if the test is "FALSE"
    )

    res_list[[i]][[j]] <- result
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, j, value = logical(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 64407
```

Comment: As a general note, analysis scripts should never call `setwd()`, and as far as I can see your script also does not require this.

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
## generating some test files in directory `./test_files`
set.seed(123)

write.csv(data.frame(ABC = rnorm(1), XYZ = rnorm(1), MNO = rnorm(1)),
          'test_files/file_1.csv')
write.csv(data.frame(XYZ = rnorm(1), DEF = rnorm(1), MNO = rnorm(1)),
          'test_files/file_2.csv')
write.csv(data.frame(ABC = rnorm(1), XYZ = rnorm(1),
                     PQR = rnorm(1), MNO = rnorm(1)),
          'test_files/file_3.csv')
```

- import and rowbind data, using `bind_rows` from package {dplyr} which can collate files despite mismatching column names:

```
library(dplyr)

d <- 
  list.files('test_files/', '\\.csv', full.names = TRUE) |>
  Map(f = \(f) read.csv(f)) |>
  Reduce(f = bind_rows)
```

example input `d`:

```
  X       ABC        XYZ       MNO        DEF       PQR
1 1 -1.067824 -0.2179749 -1.026004         NA        NA
2 1        NA -0.7288912 -1.686693 -0.6250393        NA
3 1  0.837787  0.1533731  1.253815         NA -1.138137
```

- specify checks as expressions for evaluation within `d` (so that e.g. ABC is found among `d`'s column names:

```
checklist <- list(
  check_1 = expression(ABC < 35 & ABC > 1.5 * XYZ * MNO^1.1),
  check_2 = expression(DEF < 20 & DEF > 1.5 * XYZ * MNO^1.5 * PQR)
)
```

- run through checklist, returning `TRUE` either when check conditions apply or when an error is encountered (e.g. when column name isn't found), then convert list of checks to dataframe and bind it to `d`:

```
cbind(d,
      checklist |>
      Map(f = \(check) tryCatch(eval(check, envir = d), error = \(e) TRUE)) |>
      list2DF()
      )
```

example output:

```
  X       ABC        XYZ       MNO        DEF       PQR check_1 check_2
1 1 -1.067824 -0.2179749 -1.026004         NA        NA      NA      NA
2 1        NA -0.7288912 -1.686693 -0.6250393        NA      NA      NA
3 1  0.837787  0.1533731  1.253815         NA -1.138137    TRUE      NA
```

Comment: Thank for your response but it gives me an error: Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `fail = (ABC < 35 & ABC > 1.5 * XYZ * MNO^1.1) | (DEF < 20 & DEF > 1.5 * XYZ * MNO^1.5 * PQR)`.
Caused by error:
! object 'ABC' not found

Comment: See rewritten answer (with a different approach) please.